# Passing onChange event from child to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, events, components

I want to pass the `onChange` from child to parent. I don't even know if that is the correct way of putting it. But here is my code. The code worked previously but I am trying to break down my code into smaller components and dealing with the errors. If you would like more code, I am happy to share. I am a bit new to React. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The error is basically that the function which takes the `event` isn't getting anything.

Parent:

```
        <Inputs hasInputs={hasInputs} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} thoughtProp={this.state.thought} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input } from '../Input.js'

export const Inputs = (props) => {
    return (
    <form className="flex-item-main form" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <ol>
            {props.thoughtProp.map((input, index) => (
            <Input type='text' onSubmit={props.onSubmit} key={index} value={input} onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event, index) } className='textInputs' />
            ))}
            { props.hasInputs ? (
            <input className='submitThoughts' type='submit' value='Submit Thought!' />
            ) : (
            null
            )}
        </ol>
    </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: could you please put the `console.log` in your onChange function and post what is getting you inside the onChange function in event.

Answer (score 6):

**Change Parent Component State from Child using hooks in React**

Child component holds the Input field and we are going to send the input field value to the Parent component. So let’s create the Parent component first.

**Parent.js**

```
import Child from "./Child";
   function Parent() {
        const [name, setName] = useState("");
        const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    
        const onChangeName=(newValue)=>{
          setName(newValue);
        }
    
        const onChangePassword=(value)=>{
          setPassword(value);
        }
        // We pass a callback to Child
        return (
       <Child  onChangeName={onChangeName} onChangePassword={onChangePassword} />;
    )}
```

As you see that we set the onChange property to the Child component. Next step is to create the Child component.

**Child.js**

```
    function Child(props) {
           
 return(
 <input  onChange={(e)=>{props.onChangeName(e.target.value)}} />
 <input  onChange={(e)=>{props.onChangePassword(e.target.value)}} />
       )}
```

On the above codes, we have created function handleChange that will pass the value through props.onChange to our Parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the handleChange function? In your Input component, next to your `onSubmit={props.onSubmit}` you should have `onChange={props.onChange}`.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to implement it as follows..

Parent:

```
<Inputs
  hasInputs={hasInputs}
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  thoughtProp={this.state.thought}
  onChange={(event, index) => this.handleChange(event, index)}
/>;
```

Child:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from '../Input.js';

export const Inputs = (props) => {
  return (
    <form className="flex-item-main form" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <ol>
        {props.thoughtProp.map((input, index) => (
          <Input
            type="text"
            onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
            key={index}
            value={input}
            onChange={(event, index) => props.onChange(event, index)}
            className="textInputs"
          />
        ))}
        {props.hasInputs ? (
          <input
            className="submitThoughts"
            type="submit"
            value="Submit Thought!"
          />
        ) : null}
      </ol>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am so confused why it still isn't working. I made the above changes but now when I try to type something in the inputs, literally nothing shows up in the input. It's very strange